# Drill from Bar to Pie - xAxis Still Present

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Using latest highcharts 4.0 but present under earlier versions. When I create a bar/column chart with a drillable series there are two issues that are present:

1. The `xAxis` is still viewable in the PIE chart - with nothing on it. Just a single line running the width/length of the chart area.
2. I cannot just send in the category list for the drill PIE. I must send in x/y pairs. This seems kind of silly to me.

Viewable [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/8XqMp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answers for you:

1. You need to set `showEmpty: false`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/8XqMp/17/
2. In labels formatter you should be using `this.point.name` instead, see: http://jsfiddle.net/8XqMp/19/

Comment: Almost, #2 works only if you send in [name, value] pairs. If you send in only categories with data being just the values it does not work. See http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/8XqMp/20/

Comment: In pie chart, xAxis.categories doesn't work, since there's no xAxis. That's why you need to set name for each slice.